# how to vectorize with xml data?

Tags: xml, r, language-features

let's say, I have this xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<TimeSeries>
  <timeZone>1.0</timeZone>
  <series>
    <header/>
    <event date="2009-09-30" time="10:00:00" value="0.0" flag="2"></event>
    <event date="2009-09-30" time="10:15:00" value="0.0" flag="2"></event>
    <event date="2009-09-30" time="10:30:00" value="0.0" flag="2"></event>
    <event date="2009-09-30" time="10:45:00" value="0.0" flag="2"></event>
    <event date="2009-09-30" time="11:00:00" value="0.0" flag="2"></event>
    <event date="2009-09-30" time="11:15:00" value="0.0" flag="2"></event>
  </series>
  <series>
    <header/>
    <event date="2009-09-30" time="08:00:00" value="1.0" flag="2"></event>
    <event date="2009-09-30" time="08:15:00" value="2.6" flag="2"></event>
    <event date="2009-09-30" time="09:00:00" value="6.3" flag="2"></event>
    <event date="2009-09-30" time="09:15:00" value="4.4" flag="2"></event>
    <event date="2009-09-30" time="09:30:00" value="3.9" flag="2"></event>
    <event date="2009-09-30" time="09:45:00" value="2.0" flag="2"></event>
    <event date="2009-09-30" time="10:00:00" value="1.7" flag="2"></event>
    <event date="2009-09-30" time="10:15:00" value="2.3" flag="2"></event>
    <event date="2009-09-30" time="10:30:00" value="2.0" flag="2"></event>
  </series>
  <series>
    <header/>
    <event date="2009-09-30" time="10:00:00" value="0.0" flag="2"></event>
    <event date="2009-09-30" time="10:15:00" value="0.0" flag="2"></event>
    <event date="2009-09-30" time="10:30:00" value="0.0" flag="2"></event>
    <event date="2009-09-30" time="10:45:00" value="0.0" flag="2"></event>
    <event date="2009-09-30" time="11:00:00" value="0.0" flag="2"></event>
  </series>
</TimeSeries>
```

and let's say I want to do something with its series elements and that I would like to put in practice the advice 'vectorize the vectorizable'...  I import the XML library and do the following:

```
R> library("XML")
R> doc <- xmlTreeParse('/home/mario/Desktop/sample.xml')
R> TimeSeriesNode <- xmlRoot(doc)
R> seriesNodes <- xmlElementsByTagName(TimeSeriesNode, "series")
R> length(seriesNodes)
[1] 3
R> (function(x){length(xmlElementsByTagName(x[['series']], 'event'))}
+ )(seriesNodes)
[1] 6
R>
```

and I don't understand why I should only get the result of applying the function to the first element: I had expected three values, just as the length of seriesNodes, something like this:

```
R> mapply(length, seriesNodes)
series series series 
     7     10      6
```

oops!  I already came with the answer: "use `mapply`":

```
R> mapply(function(x){length(xmlElementsByTagName(x, 'event'))}, seriesNodes)
series series series 
     6      9      5
```

but then I see the following problem: the R-inferno tells me that I'm "loop-hiding", not "vectorizing"!  can I avoid looping at all?  ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could also use `xpathApply` or `xpathSApply`-- these functions extract node sets using an XPath specification and then execute a function each set.  Both of these functions are provided by the `XML` package.  In order to use these functions, the XML document must be parsed using `xmlInternalTreeParse` or with the `useInternalNodes` option of `xmlTreeParse` set to be true:

```
require( XML )

countEvents <- function( series ){

  events <- xmlElementsByTagName( series, 'event' )
  return( length( events ) ) 

}

doc <- xmlTreeParse( "sample.xml", useInternalNodes = T )

xpathSApply( doc, '/TimeSeries/series', countEvents )
[1] 6 9 5
```

I don't know if it is any "faster", but the code is definitely cleaner and very explicit to anyone who knows the XPath syntax and how an `apply` function operates.

Comment: the help from xpathSApply is also particularly enlightening (and I'm using the XML package anyway!).

Answer (score 3):

Since `seriesNodes` is a list of nodes, there is no easy way to avoid the implicit looping. Simple operations like getting the length are not computationally intensive, so I wouldn't lose any sleep over not being able to vectorise.

Note that you can use `sapply(seriesNodes, length)`, instead of `mapply`, since there is only one argument to the `length` function.

The "proper R way" to do things is to use `(s|m)apply` calls to extract vectors of useful bits of data, then analyse those in the usual manner.

Finally, if you really are desperate to vectorise counting events, use `names(unlist(seriesNodes))` and then count the occurances of `"series.children.event.name"` in between each occurance of `"series.name"`.  This is undoubtedly uglier, and possibly slower than the `sapply` call.